# Работа с файлом и структурами

Tags: c++, файлы, структуры

Подскажите пожалуйста,почему в файле не появляется записей,что нужно добавить/исправить

После завершения программы открываю файл куда записывал всё,а он пуст...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct scan_info
{
    char mobel[25];
    int price;
    double x_size;
    double y_size;
    int optr;
    int grey;
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    ofstream out;
    out.open("text.dat", ios::binary);
    if (!out.is_open())
    {
        cout << "ОШИБКА,ФАЙЛ НЕ ОТКРЫЛСЯ!" << endl;  
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Файл успешно открыт!\n" << endl;
        cout << "Введите кол-во принтеров:";
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        cout << "Введите информацию о принтерах!"<<endl;
        scan_info* scanners = new scan_info[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        { 
            cout <<"\n"<< i + 1 << ") model, price, x_size, y_size, optr, grey:" << endl;
            cin >> scanners[i].mobel >> scanners[i].price >> scanners[i].x_size >> scanners[i].y_size >> scanners[i].optr >> scanners[i].grey;
        }
        cout << "\nИнформация о сканерах успешно записана в бинарный файл!\n" << endl;
        cout << "\n"<< " model  price  x_size  y_size  optr  grey\n" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            cout << i + 1 <<")"<< scanners[i].mobel <<"\t"<< scanners[i].price << "\t" << scanners[i].x_size << "\t" << scanners[i].y_size << "\t" << scanners[i].optr << "\t" << scanners[i].grey << endl;
        }
        out.close();
   }

    cout << "\n Press any key ... " << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, а  в какой строке выполняется запись в файл?...

Comment: Всё вроде как исправил =)
    
    cout << i + 1 <<")"<< scanners[i].mobel <<"\t"<< scanners[i].price << "\t" << scanners[i].x_size << "\t" << scanners[i].y_size << "\t" << scanners[i].optr << "\t" << scanners[i].grey << endl;
    out << scanners[i].mobel << " " << scanners[i].price << " " << scanners[i].x_size << " " << scanners[i].y_size << " " << scanners[i].optr << " " << scanners[i].grey << endl;

Comment: Ну, вообще говоря, это вы пишете текстовый вывод, а не бинарный...

Comment: Перед `out.close` в цикле вместо  `cout` пишите в `out` и будет вам счастье.